# SAPUI5 how to debug negative cache error?

Tags: sapui5

I see this occasionally apprears in console and crashed the app:

> Uncaught Error: found in negative cache:
>   'grants/portfolio/Portfolio.controller.js' from
>   vendor/openui5-sdk/resources/grants/portfolio/Portfolio.controller.js:
>   404 - Not Found

The error goes away after refreshing the page and it is hard to predict when it is going to apprear again. What is the couse of this error and/or how to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it away with control + F5.

This error happens when your SAPUI5 page tries to load a resource and fails (e.g. there is a mistake in the code or reference to the file, resulting in inproper loading of the resource).

The browser remembers that the request failed, and rather than try to call the exact same resource it informs you that it doesn't work.

Comment: Check your sources in the F12 developer tools. Has it loaded the file properly? if not, there may be a problem with finding the file, because of a slight path or name problem. If so, check the code inside the controller (comment out all the custom code, and start adding pieces until you find the culprit)

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown in the UI5 core code that downloads modules.

A map of modules to be loaded is built-up, downloaded if needed, and a status is assigned to each module, such as LOADED, READY, FAILED, etc.

If a module has been assigned the FAILED status it [throws the error](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/jquery.sap.global.js#L2804) you are seeing.

Situations where this can occur are:

- [if the ajax call fails](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/jquery.sap.global.js#L2833) (ex: 404)
- [if the module fails during exec](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/jquery.sap.global.js#L2933)

More than likely you are seeing this error because something in your deployment strategy has failed (you are getting a 404). You are not seeing the error every time because your browser cache is kicking in.

To debug this issue I would do an "[Empty Cache and Hard Reload](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/empty-cache-hard-reload-chrome)" in Chrome to eliminate any caching so you can make sure that file is being properly downloaded consistently.